# WiFi frequency channel change

Tags: networking, wireless, router

I am trying to change wifi channel to one that will use 5GHz frequency.

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

Once I connect to my Wifi, frequency is switched to 2.4GHz

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"PiotryStephy"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C0:05:C2:BF:6F:79   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

In my router settings there are both 2 and 5GHz frequencies allowed. There is no option to change "Mode:Managed".

These are my available channels:

```
iwlist channel
lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      29 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

eno1      no frequency information.
```

When I am trying to change a channel:

```
sudo iwconfig wlo1 channel 40
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlo1 ; Operation not supported.
```

Comment: In `iwconfig`, it says "Mode:Managed." In that case, the router or other access point sets (manages) the channel, not the user. I suggest that you change the router to a fixed channel: 40.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed to a fixed channel but it still connects only to a channels representing 2GHz frequencies. I can not disable this frequencies in router, because other user do not support 5GHz frequencies...

Comment: Can you assign a different SSID to the 5gHz segment; for instance, myrouter5 and the 2.4 gHz segment named myrouter24? That's the technique I use on both of my wireless routers.

Comment: I tried doing this. And 5GHz is not recognized. Possible drivers issues of my `08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)`

Comment: Not likely as the 5 gHz channels are recognized in `iwlist channel`. Did you try rebooting both the router and the computer? Is the 5 gHz segment set to fixed channel 40?

Comment: Yes, I tried rebooting. It is set to 40, but I tried manual mode with other channels and also with auto  mode.

Comment: When the router is set to channel 40, does your Broadcom simply not see it? Does it appear in `sudo iwlist scan`?

Comment: Thanks for following this topic. It does not appear. There are no channels higher than 11

Comment: Please see: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Broadcom-BCM43142-802-11-bgn-Wi-Fi-M-2-Adapter-to-5Ghz/td-p/6085221 Is it possible that only one wire is connected? Does the 5 gHz segment appear if you scan right next to the router?

Comment: Thank U. Distance from a router does not affect visibility of 5GHz networks. Might be a hardware problem indeed...

Answer (score 4):

Interface has to be in monitor mode.
First bring it down with ***ifconfig wlo1 down***
Then change it with ***iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor***
Bring it back up ***ifconfig wlo1 up***
Change channel ***iwconfig wlo1 channel 40***

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes changing channel will be on auto mode therefore these command won't helpful because it changes to 5GHz or 2.4GHz automatically
`iwlist` channel shows which channel to select.

```
iwconfig wlp2so freq 2.4G
iwconfig wlp2so channel 44
```

You need to make changes on wireless router and set manual channel select. See the image below

[image: Wireless settings on Router]